# passing dataframe to function after Group by

Tags: python, pandas

i have a df.
in which i am doing group by one column and then i want that dataframe to be passed in my function.

```
def func(dataframe):
     ....

df = df.groupby(['col1']).func.reset_index()
```

but i am getting error

```
'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute func
```

tried using various methods like

```
1.  df = df.groupby(['col1']).func().reset_index()  #not working
2.  df = df.groupby(['col1']).reset_index()
    df = df.func.reset_index()    #not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['col1']).apply(func).reset_index()
```